# How to add video stream in peerside with WebRTC connection?

Tags: reactjs, webrtc

I am building video call application with webrtc in reacJS. The logic i am using is

1. User1 enters the room, turn the video on,
2. user2 enters the room. Both can see each other.
   But In my case
   User1 enters the room, Can turn the video.
   user2 enters the room . user1 can see both of them. but user2 cant able to see user1.

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import peer from "../service/peer";
import { useSocket } from "../context/SocketProvider";

const RoomPage = () => {
  const socket = useSocket();
  const [remoteSocketId, setRemoteSocketId] = useState(null);
  const [myStream, setMyStream] = useState();
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState();
  
  const handleUserJoined = useCallback(async({ email, id }) => {
    console.log(`Email ${email} joined room`);
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: true,
    });
    setRemoteStream(stream)
    setRemoteSocketId(id);
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    const initStream = async () => {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true,
      });
      setMyStream(stream);
    };

    initStream();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("user:joined", handleUserJoined);

    return () => {
      socket.off("user:joined", handleUserJoined);
    };
  }, [
    socket,
    handleUserJoined
  ]);

 return(<div>
    {myStream && (
      <>
        <h1>My Stream</h1>
        <ReactPlayer
          playing
          muted
          height="100px"
          width="200px"
          url={myStream}
        />
      </>
    )}

    {remoteStream && (
      <>
        <h1>Remote Stream</h1>
        <ReactPlayer
          playing
          muted
          height="100px"
          width="200px"
          url={remoteStream}
        />
      </>
    )}
  </div>)
};

export default RoomPage;
```

peer.js

```
class PeerService {
  constructor() {
    if (!this.peer) {
      this.peer = new RTCPeerConnection({
        iceServers: [
          {
            urls: [
              "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
              "stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478",
            ],
          },
        ],
      });
    }
  }

}

export default new PeerService();
```

room.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import peer from "../service/peer";
import { useSocket } from "../context/SocketProvider";

const RoomPage = () => {
  const socket = useSocket();
  const [remoteSocketId, setRemoteSocketId] = useState(null);
  const [myStream, setMyStream] = useState();
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState();
  
  const handleUserJoined = useCallback(async({ email, id }) => {
    console.log(`Email ${email} joined room`);
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: true,
    });
    setRemoteStream(stream)
    setRemoteSocketId(id);
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    const initStream = async () => {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true,
      });
      setMyStream(stream);
    };

    initStream();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("user:joined", handleUserJoined);

    return () => {
      socket.off("user:joined", handleUserJoined);
    };
  }, [
    socket,
    handleUserJoined
  ]);

 return(<div>
    {myStream && (
      <>
        <h1>My Stream</h1>
        <ReactPlayer
          playing
          muted
          height="100px"
          width="200px"
          url={myStream}
        />
      </>
    )}

    {remoteStream && (
      <>
        <h1>Remote Stream</h1>
        <ReactPlayer
          playing
          muted
          height="100px"
          width="200px"
          url={remoteStream}
        />
      </>
    )}
  </div>)
};

export default RoomPage;
```